# Weight function calculation for dynamic output

Tags: statistics, regression, classification, data-science, logistic-regression

I am trying to prepare a weight function whose output should lie in `(min_output_value, max_output_value)` and the output depends on the difference of actual and target value of `y`, i.e. `(y_actual, y_target)`.

The output value should tend towards the `max_output_value` if `(y_actual - y_target)` is more and if the difference is less, the output value should tend to `min_output_value`.

Any link pointing to the answers are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some R&D, I came up with a solution, which as follows:

`y_diff = absolute(y_target - y_actual)`

`denominator = (1 + exp(-(min_output_value/10)*y_diff ))`

`output = (max_output_value/ denominator)`

This ensures that the output value always lies in the range `[min_output_value, min_output_value]`

Rounding is optional.